# Add and Find an Embedded Document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, coffeescript

I am using MongoDB + Node.js + Mongoose and `Custphones` are embedded into `Account`. 
When I add a new embedded document like this it works fine:

```
account.custphones.push { phone: '123456' }
                            account.save (err, res) ->
                                console.log res 
                                if err 
                                    throw err
```

But when I search:

```
account.custphones.find {phone: "123456"}, (err, custphone) ->
```

It says  `TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'find'`

I want to get the Custphone that is embedded into the Account.

Comment: It seems that account is your document and custphones is an attribute in your account document.

You probably need to try something like this:

 account.find {custphones.phone: "123456"} ...

I think you just need to use the 'dot' notation.    I don't really know nodejs so I am not sure the right syntax, but the point is to look at the 'dot' notation.

Comment: @agarcian that makes sense but I only get the Account object. I want to be able to have the Custphone object. Custphone is an embedded document of account.

Comment: I believe that is not possible.  I have had this kind of problem and with all the searches, you always end up with the document containing what your search matched.

So, what you end up doing in that case is finding the account object that matches your search and then accessing the embedded object with `account.custphones`

Comment: @agarcian - if I do account.custphones I'll have to cycle trough the array. having the object would be good. It's hard to believe that they didn't think about that. thanks

Comment: I know it's old but if other people come across... You could use a reference in your schema http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html That way you will be able to search for custphones only with something like `Custphone.find(...)`. When accessing the Account documents, you could populate the custphones field.